# display:flex expands row when elements fill over 100%

Tags: flexbox

Why is display:flex on #skipperForm producing weird result of all elements on same line?
Curiously, if we change to display:block we get a much better result. But why is flex not working?

```css
body{

    max-width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#links a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#links ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 15px;
    padding:0;
}

#links li{
    display:inline;
}

#skipperForm{
    display:flex;    
    justify-content:center;
    margin-top:20px;


}

.radio, .dt, .bc, .label{
    width:20vw;
    margin:0;
    max-width:200px;
    
}

.label{
    display:inline-flex;
    justify-content:center;
    font-size:20px;
}

.break{
    flex-basis:100%;
    height:0;
}

#text{
    width:60%;
}

.row{
    margin-bottom:25px;
}
```

```html
<form id='skipperForm'>
  <label class='label' for='res'>Reservation</label>
  <label class='label' for='sail'>Sail</label>
  <label class='label' for='xcl'>Cancel</label>

  <div class='break'></div>

  <input id='res' type='radio' class='radio row' name='sailType' value='RES'>
  <input id='sail' type='radio' class='radio row' name='sailType' value='SAIL'>
  <input id='xcl' type='radio' class='radio row' name='sailType' value='XCL'>

  <div class='break'></div>

  <label class='label' for='date'>Date</label>
  <label class='label' for='start'>Start Time</label>
  <label class='label' for='end'>End Time</label>

  <div class='break'></div>

  <input id='date' type='text' class='dt row' name='date'>
  <input id='start' type='text' class='dt row' name='start'>
  <input id='end' type='text' class='dt row' name='end'>

  <div class='break'></div>

  <label class='label' for='boat'>Boat</label>
  <label class='label' for='spots'>Crew Spots</label>
  <label class='label' for='customCrew'>Custom Crew</label>

  <div class='break'></div>

  <input id='boat' type='text' class='bc row' name='boat'>
  <input id='spots' type='text' class='bc row' name='spots'>
  <input id='customCrew' type='text' class='bc row' name='customCrew'>

  <div class='break'></div>

  <textarea id='text' class='row' placeholder='message crew'></textarea>

  <div class='break'></div>

  <input type='submit' class='row' name='submit' value='update'>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`display: flex;` puts all elements on the same row by default. If you one them stacked on top you need also set `flex-direction:column;`

Comment: nope, I just needed to add flex-wrap:wrap

Comment: OK. Sorry i missunderstood the question. However it is still true :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want them to be displayed in row without over cross page width you can add only one line of code to your skipperForm div like this: `flex-wrap:wrap;`

```css
body{

    max-width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#links a{
    text-decoration:none;
}

#links ul{
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0 15px;
    padding:0;
}

#links li{
    display:inline;
}

#skipperForm{
    display:flex; 
    flex-wrap:wrap;   
    justify-content:center;
    margin-top:20px;


}

.radio, .dt, .bc, .label{
    width:20vw;
    margin:0;
    max-width:200px;
    
}

.label{
    display:inline-flex;
    justify-content:center;
    font-size:20px;
}

.break{
    flex-basis:100%;
    height:0;
}

#text{
    width:60%;
}

.row{
    margin-bottom:25px;
}
```

```html
<form id='skipperForm'>
  <label class='label' for='res'>Reservation</label>
  <label class='label' for='sail'>Sail</label>
  <label class='label' for='xcl'>Cancel</label>

  <div class='break'></div>

  <input id='res' type='radio' class='radio row' name='sailType' value='RES'>
  <input id='sail' type='radio' class='radio row' name='sailType' value='SAIL'>
  <input id='xcl' type='radio' class='radio row' name='sailType' value='XCL'>

  <div class='break'></div>

  <label class='label' for='date'>Date</label>
  <label class='label' for='start'>Start Time</label>
  <label class='label' for='end'>End Time</label>

  <div class='break'></div>

  <input id='date' type='text' class='dt row' name='date'>
  <input id='start' type='text' class='dt row' name='start'>
  <input id='end' type='text' class='dt row' name='end'>

  <div class='break'></div>

  <label class='label' for='boat'>Boat</label>
  <label class='label' for='spots'>Crew Spots</label>
  <label class='label' for='customCrew'>Custom Crew</label>

  <div class='break'></div>

  <input id='boat' type='text' class='bc row' name='boat'>
  <input id='spots' type='text' class='bc row' name='spots'>
  <input id='customCrew' type='text' class='bc row' name='customCrew'>

  <div class='break'></div>

  <textarea id='text' class='row' placeholder='message crew'></textarea>

  <div class='break'></div>

  <input type='submit' class='row' name='submit' value='update'>

</form>
```